# TypeError: newUser.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am very new to the MERN stack and I would like some help figuring out this error. I'm trying to check if an email is already in the database upon creating a new user. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

The model and scheme

```
//schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const VerificationSchema = new Schema({
  FullName: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  date: Date,
  isVerified: Boolean,
});
// Model
const User = mongoose.model("Users", VerificationSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

The Api

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const User = require("../Models/User");

router.get("/VerifyEmail", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Body:", req.body);
  const data = req.body;

  const newUser = new User();

  newUser.find({ email: data.email }, function (err, newUser) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (newUser) {
      console.log("ErrorMessage: This email already exists");
    } else {
      console.log("This email is valid");
    }
  });

  res.json({
    msg: "We received your data!!!",
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The api caller using axios

```
const isEmailValid = (value) => {
  const info = {
    email: value,
  };
  axios({
    url: "http://localhost:3001/api/VerifyEmail",
    method: "get",
    data: info,
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Data has been sent");
      console.log(info);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("Internal server error");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't actually the mongoose function but I needed to parse the object being sent.

let { email } = JSON.parse(req.body);

Before parsing the object looked like {"email" : "something@gmail.com"}

and after parsing the object looked like {email: 'something@gmail.com'}

I also changed the request from 'get' to 'post' and instead of creating a new instance of the model I simply used User.find() instead of newUser.find()

Answer (score 0):

if you have body in your request, change the type of request to `POST`...
after that for use `find` don't need to create a instance of model, use `find` with `Model`

```
router.get("/VerifyEmail", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Body:", req.body);
 const data = req.body;
  User.find({ email: data.email }, function (err, newUser) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (newUser) {
      console.log("ErrorMessage: This email already exists");
    } else {
      console.log("This email is valid");
    }
  });

  res.json({
    msg: "We received your data!!!",
  });
});
```

I prefer to use `async/await` and don't use Uppercase world for routing check the [article](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/): like this

```
router.post("/verify-email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let { email } = req.body;
    let newUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (newUser) {
      console.log("ErrorMessage: This email already exists");
    } else {
      console.log("This email is valid");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({
      msg: "somthing went wrong",
    });
  }
  res.json({
    msg: "We received your data!!!",
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to query a Model is like so:

```
const User = mongoose.model('Users');

User.find({<query>}, function (err, newUser) {...
```

So you need to get the model into a variable (in this case `User`) and then run the `find` function directly against it, as opposed to running it against an object you instantiate from it. So this is incorrect:

```
const newUser = new User();
newUser.find(...
```

So assuming all your files and modules are linked up correctly, this should work:

```
const User = require("../Models/User");
User.find({<query>}, function (err, newUser) {...
```